# Computation of an Ito Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following Ito Integral

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{t}B_se^{-\sigma B_S}dB_s&& \end{align} $$

Here, $\sigma \gt 0$.

Can someone please show me how to compute this Ito integral? Thanks much!

Comment: Always "Did" say: What does "solve an Itô integral" actually means?.

Comment: I tell you: Indeed it is meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps we all know how to compute $\int_0^t x e^{-\sigma x} \mathrm{d}x$.  The Question might then be asked what different meaning can be assigned with $x$ replaced by a random variable.  Certainly nothing can be computed (such as an expected value) unless the distribution of $B_s$ is known.